# Parametric file inclusion in struts.xml configurations, based on properties

Tags: spring, properties, struts2

I have a web application (built on Spring, Struts 2) and I am trying to dynamically include  a struts configuration file inside the main struts.xml configuration, based on a property.

Having defined, in the property file:

```
key=foo
```

I try to use it inside struts.xml:

```
<struts>
   ...
   <include file="/config/struts/struts-${key}.xml" />
</struts>
```

To include the "struts-foo.xml" file (or another file, depending on the value).

The property file is loaded at startup by Spring, and I am able to use it inside Spring's xml files to parametrize bean definition.

Comment: struts.xml file isn't loaded by spring.

Comment: thanks Aleksandr; is there another way to read a property/parameter inside struts files?

Comment: You can substitute keyword when you're building your app. Or include all files in struts.xml and copy only some of them into package.

Comment: Yes, it sounds definitely a job for a Maven task (or whatever). Also keep in mind that to achieve full testability, the reproducibility of a build matters, and hence (in a perfect world) the build should always be the same, no matter if the environment is dev or prod, and the configurations should be external to it, for example in environment variables or in a file on the server itself. That said, why do you need to include different struts.xml ? That's a weird use-case, [most likely XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I am working on a webapp that will go live in two different sites: they will be very similar to each others with some minor customizations, let's say 85% common vs 15% custom. Where I work we usually solve this either by branching the whole code base, or by filling the code with `if(site1)..else if (site2)`, and I don't like these solutions... This was an attempt to  modularize customization and only load them according with the local installation, guided by a property (in these question I am asking about action mapping, but I used the same system to load different spring bean).

Comment: Yes, branching the code base sucks but is the usual solution (however better than hard-coupling the code with internal checks). The other main option is to shift everything to microservices, including the UI, but that's a hell of refactoring, especially for the italian market :/

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the Struts2 plugin framework.

You basically create a jar based project where you include all of a particular client's action mappings, support classes, etc.  If you're also deploying into a Servlet 3.0 or higher container, you can also elect to include the UI artifacts inside the jar's META-INF\resources directory too for clean packaging.

Now, the contents you typically place inside the struts.xml for action mappings, you simply place inside struts-plugin.xml and place this xml file in the root of the jar file.

When the Struts2 framework starts, the jar files will be scanned, the struts-plugin.xml files will be picked up and automatically included in your application.

I use the same setup in conjunction with my maven build process so that if a client's deployment isn't suppose to include a specific feature or if a standard feature is to be customized, I can customize the action mappings from the stock ones.

In our case, the stock app is a struts-plugin based jar that gets loaded before any other jars and then subsequent feature jars are loaded to extend or override functionality.  The actual WAR project has little inside it and is mainly an artifact used to deploy combinations of other project artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

As you know you can change the struts.xml config file name, as below:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

You can use this feature to change struts.xml dynamicly.

You need to extend the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and load your dynamic config here.  Replace your new fildter with struts in `web.xml`.

```
public class MyStrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter extends StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter{

    @Override
    protected void postInit(Dispatcher dispatcher, FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        //load your config here        

    }

}
```

Please have a look at `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` source code. you can see how the config is loaded and you can how you can change it.

---

If you want to only dynamical change your application messages you can do it more easily by just calling  `LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle ("messages/customize")` in `MyStrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`